# type 'IModelExpressionProvider' doesn't exist in a dependecy package

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, typeerror

Visual Studio says I've referred to the type IModelExpressionProvider when I don't believe I have. I keep getting a 500 internal server error that throws a system.typeloadexception when trying to build my project. The error I receive is:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

This seems like an extremely simple issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TheWorld
{
    public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(config =>
        {
            config.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
                );
        });
    }
}
}
```

## project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
"jQuery": "3.1.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
     "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
  },

"buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder     %publish:OutputPath% -    -framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
      }
    }
```

## AppController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace TheWorld.Controllers.Web
{
    public class AppController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>The World - @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar" class="hide-sidebar">
        <img src="img/IMG_20150718_175925.jpg" alt="headshot" class="headshot" />
        <span id="username">Jordan Mickel</span>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="hide-sidebar">
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <button id="sidebarToggle">Toggle Menu</button>
            </div>
            <h3>The World</h3>
            <p>This will be a fun website soon!</p>

            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Location</label>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Add" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            &copy; 2017 The World Ltd.
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```